# how to update bulk test cases status in rally from excel

Tags: java, excel, rally, vba

I am new to rally and want to update bulk test cases status(Pass/Fail) in rally using excel macro or using java. Can anyone please help.

Comment: What do you mean by rally?  Please make it more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

Agile Central (previously known as Rally), does not allow you to update the status of a testcase directly. You have to add a testcaseresult to it.

If you look in the WSAPI docs (via the help), you may get a better understanding of what you can update in the artefact tables. SOme of the fields are shown as "Read Only" and are generated by the Agile Central backend when you read the artefact.